# Inflate different menu depending on boolean condition

Tags: java, android

I have a favourites feature where users can add favourite recipes and then remove them afterwards. I have a menu item on the actionbar which can perform these two actions. I have two different menus for this. When the Fragment for the recipe page is displayed, a check is performed to see if the recipe has or has not been favourited for the user. If it has been favourited, the "delete" icon should appear, but if it has not, then the "add to favourites" icon should appear.

However, when I test loading a favourited recipe page, the "add to favourites" button is displayed like this:

[image]

But when I switch to another tab and then switch back, the correct delete icon is displayed.

[image]

Why is this not displaying the correct menu on the first attempt?

**IngredientsFragment.java**

```
 boolean exists;

  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    new CheckFavourite().execute();
    getExistence();

    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {

        if (exists){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_from_favs, menu);
        }

        else  {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_to_favs, menu);

        }

    }
    restoreActionBar();

}

class CheckFavourite extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String user_id, recipe_id;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        user_id = session.getID();
        recipe_id = result.getRecipeId();

        System.out.println("User ID: " + user_id);
        System.out.println("recipe ID: " + recipe_id);
    }

    /**
     * Checking favourites
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id);
        params.put("recipe_id", recipe_id);


        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("MyWebsiteURL",
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            System.out.println(success);

            if (success == 1) {
                setTrue();
                Log.d("Exist", json.toString());

            } else {
                setFalse();
                Log.d("Does not exist", json.toString());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done


    }

}

public boolean getExistence(){
    return this.exists;
}

public void setTrue(){
    exists = true;
}

public void setFalse(){
    exists = false;
}
```

**add_to_favs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/favourites"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/favourites"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**delete_from_favs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/delete"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom">
</item>

</menu>
```

I have tried so many things from putting both menu items in the same menu and setting one or the other as visible/invisible. I also tried using the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method but this resulted in the same outcome. I know I'm missing something stupid. Please help!

Comment: have you used setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your code?

Comment: @HRaval yes, this is done inside my onCreateView method

Comment: whats the value of "exists" when the menu is created for the first time..

Comment: @MeenalSharma there is no defined value. but the same outcome happened when I assigned it "false"

Answer (score 0):

just use one menu and have both items inside it....and programatically hide/show it..

menu.xml (inside your activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/favourites"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/favourites"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom">
    </item>

<item android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/delete"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom">
</item>
</menu>
```

inside on create view

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 MenuItem fav = menu.findItem(R.id.favourites);
 fav.setVisible(true);

MenuItem del = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
 del.setVisible(true);
}

//based on condition
 if (session.isLoggedIn()) {

        if (exists){
           del.setVisibility(true);
           fav.setVisibility(false);
        }else{
          fav.setVisibility(true);
          del.setVisibility(false);
      }
}
}
```

Comment: where do I inflate my menu?

Comment: also it is still displaying the "add to favourites" icon first

Comment: infliate your menu in your activity